# Alternative theorem styles with amsthm package?

Tags: amsthm

I am writing a document with many lemmas, theorems, and proofs. I don't like the default styling available, mainly because it places almost no visual separation between theorems and text (or proofs and text).

I would like the following:

A definiton environment with larger margins and a vertical line on the left side, so I can clearly see where the definition starts and ends, by noticing where the vertical line begins and ends.

Is there any theorem style that would achieve this? Any similar style which would at least make the theorems and proofs stand out from the text?

Thanks!

p.s. Currently, I end a definition block with a `\( \qed \)` so there is some indication that the definition ended.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`mdframed:`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed:)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newmdtheoremenv[
  linecolor=cyan,
  roundcorner=5pt,
  linewidth=1pt
]{theo}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newmdtheoremenv[
  hidealllines=true,
  leftline=true,
  innerleftmargin=10pt,
  innerrightmargin=10pt,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
]{defi}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{defi}
\lipsum[4]
\end{defi}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{theo}
\lipsum[4]
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The package offers many additional customization options; please refer to the package documentation which also contains numerous examples.

If a same style is to be used for several structures, then it's better to define a style to be used multiple times; the package also offers a very useful `\surroundwithmdframed` command to apply mdframed settings to an already defined environment. In the following example I define a style, built an structure for definitions using this style, and surround the standard `proof` environment (from `amsthm`) with this style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  hidealllines=true,
  leftline=true,
  innerleftmargin=10pt,
  innerrightmargin=10pt,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
}
\surroundwithmdframed[style=mystyle]{proof}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=mystyle]{defi}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{defi}
\lipsum[4]
\end{defi}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{proof}
\lipsum*[4]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again! Now, if I wanted to place the proof in the same environment, would it be as simple as adding it inside the ``defi`` environment?

Comment: @Gonzalo You're welcome! It would be even simpler once you define a style and use `\surroundedwithmdframed`. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina these are nice solutions. However, I'm interested in something simpler. Part of the original post was a query on how to increase the "visual separation between theorems and text" that is part of the default styles. I can't see how this is achieved amongst all of the other features. Could you point this out please?

Comment: @JasonWhyte in that case, simply use `\newtheoremstyle` from the `amsthm` package and build a style with extra vertical separation with the surrounding text.